# MongoDb C# Driver is not working properly for documents with long strings

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have a project made with .net6 and MongoDb driver 2.19.1. When I try to list all documents in a collection like this:

```
 /// <inheritdoc/>
 public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filterExpression)
        {
            var result = await _collection.FindAsync(filterExpression);

            return result.ToEnumerable();
        }
```

It works but for documents with long string values it its returning values like this:

```
_id: 6446f33258555705d7d36582
RequestJSon: "{"Country":1,"Operation":1,"PropertyType":1,"Locale":null,"Center":"40…"
ResponseJSon: "{"Total":18317,"TotalPages":367,"ActualPage":1,"ItemsPerPage":50,"NumP…"
```

I checked that the properties RequestJSon and ResponseJSon do have a big value not cantains any "...". So it seems somehow mongoDb client is truncating the value.

Is there any way to force it to load the complete document ?

Comment: How do you know that the response contains three dots? Debugging tools or you receive an error when it tries to parse the data..?

Comment: I received an error when tried to parse the data and when I debugged in Visual Studio I can see that the lenght of the string is very short

Comment: You need to specify an error message you receive when you parse the document, because it is possible that these dots come from a debugger that displays only limited number of characters, but in fact mongodb stores document properly

Comment: mongo client doesn't do any truncating logic as well as mongo server. It must be your side issue

Comment: @YehorAndrosov It seems like a caching problem because I realized the issue its not happening with all the documents, its instead a problem with the first ones, when I try to load a document that was not loaded before it works as expected. Any recomendation about how to force cache refresh or something like that?